# The Bloc isn't updaing the widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

I am building a demo quiz app in flutter using Bloc, The data is shown and I am trying to update the question and it's options. The widget isn't rebuilding I think. Everytime i click on a option, it should move to the next question, but it doesn't show any changes in the UI. it changes the question after I press hot reload.

```
class QuizCubit extends Cubit<QuizState> {
  QuizCubit() : super(QuizInitialState()) {
    drawQuizData();
  }
  QuizBrain quizBrain = QuizBrain();
  late QuizResult result;

  drawQuizData() async {
    emit(QuizLoadingDemoState());
    await Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    emit(QuizDataState(
      quizBrain: quizBrain,
    ));
  }

  void pickedOption() {
    quizBrain.toNextQuestion();
    if (quizBrain.isLastQuestion()) {
      emit(QuizQuizCompletedState());
    } else {
      emit(QuizPickedOptionState());
    }
  }
}


pickedOption
```

is the function responsible
The quiz logic is fine as it is working without bloc without any issues.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            BlocConsumer<QuizCubit, QuizState>(
              listener: (context, state) {
                if (state is QuizQuizCompletedState) {
                  // Handle quiz completion here.
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(
                      content: const Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.info_outline,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                          Text(
                            "Success",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade300,
                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                      action: SnackBarAction(
                        label: 'Close',
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Add any action you want here
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is QuizActionState,
              bloc: quizCubit,
              buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is! QuizActionState,
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is QuizLoadingDemoState) {
                  return const CupertinoActivityIndicator();
                }
                if (state is QuizPickedOptionState) {
                  // emit();
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
                if (state is QuizDataState) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "${state.quizBrain.questionNumber + 1}: ",
                            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            state.quizBrain.quizQuestion(),
                            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 120,
                        width: 210,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: state.quizBrain.quizOptions().length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                //   quizCubit.pickedOption(
                                //   state.quizBrain.quizOptions()[index],
                                // );
                                quizCubit.pickedOption(
                                    );
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                state.quizBrain.quizOptions()[index],
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
                return const Text("123");
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );



quizCubit.pickedOption(
                                        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be from the state management in your `QuizCubit`. When you call the `pickedOption` function, you are updating the `QuizBrain` object, but this doesn't necessarily trigger a re-render of the widget because you're only emitting the `QuizPickedOptionState()` or the `QuizQuizCompletedState()` without carrying over the updated data.

Here are a few steps you can take to resolve this issue:

1. **Modify the States to Include the Updated Data**: Every time you emit a new state from the `QuizCubit`, make sure it carries the updated data. For instance, you could include the updated `QuizBrain` object in both the `QuizPickedOptionState` and `QuizQuizCompletedState`.

```dart
class QuizPickedOptionState extends QuizState {
  final QuizBrain quizBrain;
  QuizPickedOptionState({required this.quizBrain});
}

class QuizQuizCompletedState extends QuizState {
  final QuizBrain quizBrain;
  QuizQuizCompletedState({required this.quizBrain});
}
```

2. **Emit the States with the Updated Data**:

Update your `pickedOption` method to include the updated `quizBrain`:

```dart
void pickedOption() {
  quizBrain.toNextQuestion();
  if (quizBrain.isLastQuestion()) {
    emit(QuizQuizCompletedState(quizBrain: quizBrain));
  } else {
    emit(QuizPickedOptionState(quizBrain: quizBrain));
  }
}
```

3. **Update the Widget Rendering Logic**:

Now, in your `BlocConsumer`, you should account for the states you modified:

```dart
//...
builder: (context, state) {
  if (state is QuizLoadingDemoState) {
    return const CupertinoActivityIndicator();
  }
  if (state is QuizPickedOptionState || state is QuizDataState || state is QuizQuizCompletedState) {
    var quizBrainToUse = state is QuizDataState 
        ? state.quizBrain 
        : (state is QuizPickedOptionState ? state.quizBrain : null);
        
    // Return your UI here using `quizBrainToUse`.
    // ...
  }
  return const Text("123");
}
//...
```

With these changes, your widget should be able to re-render and show updated data whenever there's a state change in your `QuizCubit`.

Lastly, ensure that the methods within `QuizBrain` (e.g., `toNextQuestion`, `quizQuestion`, and `quizOptions`) are functioning correctly and returning the expected data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the answer myself.
The answer to it is instead of emitting the new state, I just emitted the old state again.

Here is the code for it.

```
void pickedOption() {
    quizBrain.toNextQuestion();
    if (quizBrain.isLastQuestion()) {
      quizBrain.reset();
      emit(QuizQuizCompletedState());
    } else {
      emit(QuizDataState(quizBrain: quizBrain));
    }
  }
```